# Substitute $x^4$ with $4\cdot x^3$ in a differential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working through a book to learn differential equations. There is a step of solution, and I don't get two things:

1. How is possible to substitute $\frac{1}{16}x^4$ with $\color{red}{\frac1{16}(4\cdot x^3)}$
2. Why did they substitute the $y$ function on the left side where the $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$ was. I would expect to put $\color{blue}{xy^{1/2}}$?

See the picture:

> [image]

Comment: 1) They didn't.  $y = \frac 1{16}x^4$ so the *derivative* of $y$ is $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {d\frac 1{16}x^4}{dx} = \frac 1{16}\cdot 4 \cdot x^3$.

Comment: aha so "d" and one "x' was cancelled? but how appeared the 4 then?

Comment: "d" was cancelled? No. Not at all. The $d$ is not an algebraic letter that may be cancelled above and below the fraction line. Not even close. In fact, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ isn't even a fraction (although it's specifically meant to look like one, because of reasons).

Comment: By the way, [here](https://i.imgur.com/oMc81Ym.png) is a more correct version of your picture.

Comment: $\frac {dy}{dx}$ means the *derivative* of $y$ (which is a function of $x$).  If $y = f(x) = \frac 1{16}x^4$ then $\frac {dy}{dx} = f'(x) = \frac 1{16}\cdot 4\cdot x^3$.  This is not supposed to be hard or confusing.  We need to show that if $y = f(x) =\frac 1{16}x^4$ then that is *one* function where $f'(x) = x\sqrt{f(x)}$.  Or in Leibniz notation (which is the *practical* notation for differential equations) where $\frac {dy}{dx} = xy^{\frac 12}$.

Comment: ok thanks for info to all. now i am little bit smarter and less confused. i will probably also check some pre calculus then

Comment: Calculus is *certainly* a prerequisite to differential equations.  You must forgive us but we all assumed you had completed calculus.  There is simply no way you will be able to understand differential equations if you have not completed calculus.

Comment: @fleablood For what it's worth, I thought there was a 60% chance luky was confused about substituting functions and a 30% chance luky was not aware of derivatives. I wrote my answer to fill in some of the missing details so that luky could have something more precise to point to, to help reveal which it was.

Comment: @fleablood yes that's ok, you just pointed me at correct way, that's ok. well i have some basic grasp of calculus meaning i have some clue what is function, what is derivate etc, but i didn't have the technique of how to differentiate etc. so once i will learn this, i guess i can continue on the DE book. i am learning math randomly :). randomly filling the missing gaps.

Comment: @KyleMiller I will return later back on this question and will read it all again, thank you.

Comment: @fleablood you really helped me with the explaining it is a derivate etc. because it was not understable from the book :) etc.

Comment: I strongly advise not skipping about.  You really need the skill to know how to differentiate before you move on.  Study *and complete* calculus before you do *anything* else is my advice. (Okay, you can do discrete math... but I wouldn't do anything else.  That's my advice.)

Comment: @fleablood Yes. I mean i have big gaps in the math so I am learning randomly. I now found some very nice book about Calculus it is called "INTRODUCTION TO DIFFERENTIAL CALCULUS" by Ulrich L. Rohde. It looks really good and it covers lot of topic in the detail. Any tips on good books? The books are really different this one is one of best to me. https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Differential-Calculus-Engineering-Applications/dp/1118117751

Answer (score 4):

The left-hand side of $dy/dx = xy^{1/2}$ is $dy/dx$, which means "$d/dx$ of $y$."  Let's substitute in $y=\tfrac{1}{16}x^4$:
$$dy/dx = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{16}x^4\right)=\frac{1}{16}\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^4\right)=\frac{1}{16}\left(4x^3\right)=\frac{1}{4}x^3.$$
The right-hand side is $xy^{1/2}$, and when we substitute in $y=\tfrac{1}{16}x^4$ we get
$$xy^{1/2}=x\left(\frac{1}{16}x^4\right)^{1/2}=x\left(\frac{1}{4}x^2\right)=\frac{1}{4}x^3.$$
Since both sides are equal after this substitution, we say that the function $y=\tfrac{1}{16}x^4$ is a solution to the differential equation $dy/dx = xy^{1/2}$.

A key thing to remember with differential equations is that $y$ is implicitly a function of the independent variable $x$ throughout all of this.  It could clearer if $y$ were written as $y(x)$ to indicate this, so for example the differential equation is $y'(x) = xy(x)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Re final paragraph: Or forgo $y$ completely, and instead write $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$. Or use $t$ as the free variable and $x$ or $y$ as the function name. Usually, $x$ and $y$ are seen as "equals" (not as in $=$, but as in they exist on the "same level"), and putting one higher in the intuitive "hierarchy" than the other can lead to extra mental work. Especially to beginners in differential equations.

Comment: whats the explanation of turning x^4 into 4x^3?

Comment: @luky Differentiate $x^4$. What do you get?

Comment: @Arthur aha it is a derivate of x^4 hm i didnt know it https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4 it is a bit greek village to me. there was some derivate dx/dy then some function y, and then they've put another derivate of x in the y function (and even without a word)

Comment: Um..... no offense but if you did not know that $\frac {d\frac 1{16}x^4}{dx} = \frac 1{16}\cdot 4\cdot x^3$ then you are not ready to study differential equations yet.  You need to continue studying differential calculus first.

Comment: @fleablood yes i didnt know it. ok i will check it. there were no info that differential calculus is required before this. i thought i will learn it right from this book.

Comment: You were not told that calculus was a requirement for differential equations?  So.... have you taken calculus yet?  Do you know what *derivatives* are?

Comment: @fleablood I'm not sure this line of questioning is helpful.  It's clear that luky now knows that differential equations needs differential calculus, right? (And luky: if this is a course and they didn't list this prerequisite, you might communicate with the instructor about how they expect you to quickly get up to speed.)

Comment: @Arthur: I find it misleading to write $\frac{df}{dx}$ if $f$ is intended to be a function, rather than a variable. That notation would be inconsistent with $\frac{dy}{dx}$, where $y$ is typically a variable, not a function.

Answer (score -1):

The are asking you to *verify* that $y = \frac 1{16} x^4$ is a possible solution to $\frac {dy}{dx} = xy^{\frac 12}$.

So we will *assume* $y = \frac 1{16}x^4$ and *from* that we will *show* that that means $\frac {dy}{dx} = xy^{\frac 12}$ (which we do *not* assume we know.)

So  if $y = \frac 1{16}x^4$ then if we take the derivative of that we get $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac 1{16}\cdot 4\cdot x^3 = \frac 14 x^3$.

Okay... that tells us what the LHS $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is equal to.  What is the RHS $xy^{\frac 12}$ equal to.

If $y = \frac 1{16}x^4$ then $y^{\frac 12} = (\frac 1{16}x^4)^{\frac 12} = \frac 14 x^2$.  So $xy^{\frac 12} = x\cdot \frac 14 x^2 = \frac 14 x^3$.

So we have, for the equation $y = \frac 1{16}x^4$, that both $\frac {dy}{dx}$ and $xy^{\frac 12}$ are equal to the same thing they are equal to each other. So ***IF*** $y = \frac 1{16}x^4$ ***THEN*** $\frac {dy}{dx} = xy^{\frac 12}$.

SO $y= \frac 1{16}x^4$ is *one* possible solution to $\frac {dy}{dx} = xy^{\frac 12}$.

=======

Would it be easier if we use Newton Notation rather than Leibniz notation?

If $f(x) = \frac 1{16}x^4$ then show that $f'(x) = x\sqrt{f(x)}$.

Well if $f(x) = \frac 1{16}x^4$ then $f'(x)=\frac 1{16}[x^4]' = \frac 1{16}\cdot 4x^3 = \frac 14 x^3$.

And if $f(x) =\frac 1{16}x^4$ then $\sqrt{f(x)} = \frac 14 x^2$ and $x\sqrt{f(x)} = x[\frac 14 x^2] = \frac 14 x^3$.

So $f'(x)$ and $x\sqrt{f(x)}$ both are equal to the same thing so $f'(x) = \frac 14 x^3 = x\sqrt{f(x)}$ and $f(x) = \frac 1{16}x^4$ is a solution to $f'(x) =x\sqrt{f(x)}$.

....

But you *need* to get comfortable with Leibniz notation.  It is essential for the study of differential equations as we need to specify the function *as* a variable in it's own right, *and* also specify when we take the derivative with respect to *which* variable are we taking the derivative.